# Use Regex to Split Numbered List array into Numbered List Multiline

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I am trying to learn Regex to answer a question on SO portuguese.

#### Input (Array or String on a Cell, so `.MultiLine = False`)?

```
 1 One without dot. 2. Some Random String. 3.1 With SubItens. 3.2 With number 0n mid. 4. Number 9 incorrect. 11.12 More than one digit. 12.7 Ending (no word).
```

#### Output

```
 1 One without dot.
 2. Some Random String.
 3.1 With SubItens.
 3.2 With number 0n mid.
 4. Number 9 incorrect.
 11.12 More than one digit.
 12.7 Ending (no word).
```

What i thought was to use [Regex with Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1), but i wasn't able to implement the example on Excel.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Example
   Public Sub Main()
      Dim input As String = "plum-pear"
      Dim pattern As String = "(-)" 

      Dim substrings() As String = Regex.Split(input, pattern)    ' Split on hyphens.
      For Each match As String In substrings
         Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", match)
      Next
   End Sub
End Module
' The method writes the following to the console:
'    'plum'
'    '-'
'    'pear'
```

So reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops) and [this](http://analystcave.com/excel-regex-tutorial/#LVL_3_Regular_Expressions_Excel_Regex_8211_RegExp). The [RegExr Website](https://regexr.com/) was used with the expression `/([0-9]{1,2})([.]{0,1})([0-9]{0,2})/igm` on the Input.

And the following is obtained:

[image: RegExr]

Is there a better way to make this? Is the Regex Correct or a better way to generate? The examples that i found on google didn't enlight me on how to use RegEx with Split correctly.

Maybe I am confusing with the logic of Split Function, which i wanted to get the split index and the separator string was the regex.

Comment: look for String.Replace(regex) - and google BackReferences.  I *THINK* it would be something like `input.Replace("([0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)", "\0" + vbcrlf)`

Comment: Does each item always start with a numeral and end with a period? If so, you could use a simpler pattern: `\d[ .\dA-Za-z]+?\.`

Comment: No, aways start with digit. But when he is alone. Can be without period.

Comment: Does it mean your list items do not contain digits? How do you distinguish between `4` as a bullet item and `4` as a number inside the text?

Comment: Good point. I thought of that and just assumed only numbers as item bullet. But since all ends with period, i think i can make that it ends with word and period. I tried to make it starting with number and ending with word and period. Unsuccessful. I am reading a little more and making some attempts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can make that it ends with word and period

Use

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)*[\s\S]*?\w+\.
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WpiKin/1).

**Details**

- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:\.\d+)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `\.` - dot
  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `[\s\S]*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible, up to the first...
- `\w+\.` - 1+ word chars followed with `.`.

Here is a sample VBA code:

```
Dim str As String
Dim objMatches As Object
str = " 1 One without dot. 2. Some Random String. 3.1 With SubItens. 3.2 With Another SubItem. 4. List item. 11.12 More than one digit."
Set objRegExp = New regexp ' CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegExp.Pattern = "\d+(?:\.\d+)*[\s\S]*?\w+\."
objRegExp.Global = True
Set objMatches = objRegExp.Execute(str)
If objMatches.Count <> 0 Then
  For Each m In objMatches
      Debug.Print m.Value
  Next
End If
```

[image]

**NOTE**

You may require the matches to only stop at the word + `.` that are followed with 0+ whitespaces and a number using [`\d+(?:\.\d+)*[\s\S]*?[a-zA-Z]+\.(?=\s*(?:\d+|$))`](https://regex101.com/r/WpiKin/2).

The `(?=\s*(?:\d+|$))` positive lookahead requires the presence of 0+ whitespaces (`\s*`) followed with 1+ digits (`\d+`) or end of string (`$`) immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to make this RegEx totally wrong. Using `^` to start. I need to study more, because RegEx is really useful. And `?=` or `?:` are some patterns definitions that i didn't see on the tutorials. Thanks again, answer well explained

Comment: Just changed to `\d+(?:\.\d+)*[\s\S]*?[\D]+\.(?=\s*(?:\d+|$))` using `[\D]` instead of `[a-zA-Z]`. Because if the list item ended with `).` it wouldn't work.

Comment: @danieltakeshi: Note that `\D` matches any non-digit symbols. You may want to just use [`\d+(?:\.\d+)*[\s\S]*?\D\.(?=\s*(?:\d|$))`](https://regex101.com/r/WpiKin/3). As for the `^`, it can match start of the string (with `RegExp.Multiline = False`), or start of the line (with `RegExp.Multiline = True`)

Comment: @danieltakeshi And another hint: If there are no linebreaks in the string, `[\s\S]` can be replaced with `.`.

Answer (score 1):

If VBA's split supports look-behind regex then this one may work, assuming there's no digit except in the indexes:

```
    \s(?=\d)
```