# How to capture all content between two captured groups

Tags: python, regex

I have a txt file that I converted from a pdf that contains a long list of items. These items have a numbering convention as follows:

```
[A-Z]{1,2}\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}
```

This expression would match something between:

> A1.1.1

and

> ZZ99.99.99

This works just fine. The issue I am having is that I am trying to capture this in group 1 and everything between each item number (the item description) in group 2.

I also need these returned as a list or an iterable so that, eventually, the contents captured can be exported to an excel spreadsheet.

This is the regex I have currently:

```
^([A-Z]{1,2}\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\s)([\w\W]*?)(?:\n)
```

Follow this link to find a sample of what I have and the issues I am facing:

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/DDgtAHqmkI2ud5Od)

Is anyone able to help me figure out how to capture everything between each number no matter how many paragraphs?

Any input would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I don't know Python, but i had a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46331543/use-regex-to-split-numbered-list-array-into-numbered-list-multiline) recently. And this is the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/WpiKin/3). Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You are very close:

```
import re

s = """
A1.2.1 This is the first paragraph of the description that is being captured by the regex even if the description contains multiple lines of text.ZZ99.99.99
"""
final_data = re.findall("[A-Z]{1,2}\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}(.*?)[A-Z]{1,2}\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}", s)
```

Output:

```
[' This is the first paragraph of the description that is being captured by the regex even if the description contains multiple lines of text.']
```

By using `(.*?)` you can match any text between the letters and numbers as defined by your first regex.

Comment: The [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/W9NpLnVs1wYFpay8) didn't validate the code this way.