# Using regex to find paragraphs in VBA Excel

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I am trying to use regex to 'extract' paragraphs in a document. Each paragraph is preceded and followed by a '-' on separate line and each paragraph starts with a number.

For example

> -  
>   1. This is a paragraph 
>   It may go over multiple lines 
>   -

Ideally, I would like to not include the '-', but it doesn't really matter as I will be placing it in a string and running another regex against it (One that I know works)

The code I am trying to use is basically as follows

```
Dim matchPara as Object
Dim regex as Object
Dim theMatch as Object
Dim matches as Object
Dim fileName as String
Dim fileNo as Integer
Dim document as String

matchPara = "-?(\d.*?)?-"
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
regex.Pattern = matchPara
regex.Global = True
regex.Multiline = True

fileName = "C:\file.txt"
fileNo = FreeFile

Open fileName For Input As #fileNo
document = Input$(LOF(fileNo), fileNo)
set matches = regex.Execute(document)

For Each theMatch in matches
    MsgBox(theMatch.Value)
Next theMatch

Close #fileNo
```

I have tested this regex on [regex101](http://regex101.com) and it appeared to do what I wanted. I have also tested it without the grouping

> -?\d.*?-

However when I run the code the `theMatch.Value` only ever contains a single '-'. After some messing around with the regex I got it to display the first line of text but never any more than the first line.

I have checked the length of *theMatch.Value* with:

```
MsgBox(len(theMatch.Value))
```

and placed the contents of `theMatch.Value` in a cell on the worksheet to see if It was cutting off in the message box, but both theories were proved wrong.

I am at a complete loss now and I am beginning to suspect it is possibly a VBA thing and not a regex thing. There is no requirement to use regex, I just assumed it would be the easiest thing to do.

The paragraphs contain data that I am trying to extract. So the idea was to regex each paragraph out place that in a string then run other regex to get the information that I need. Some paragraphs wont contain the data that I need so the idea was to loop through each individual paragraph and then error handle better if the data I need wasn't in that paragraph (ie get what I can and drop the rest with an error message)

Here is a screenshot:

[image: regex101 Screenshot]

Comment: I don't think it's working properly on **regex101**.  Could you post a screenshot of the results from _regex101_ showing that it's returning your full paragraphs there?  Also, is there a reason this need to be done with regular expressions?  Also, what are you actually doing with the output?  (I assume the goal isn't just to show them in `MsgBox`'s?

Comment: Added screenshot and answers to your question

Comment: The RegEx in your screenshot is not the same as in your code.

Comment: No, but it's the same as the second example I gave that also doesn't work

Comment: Check this answer: [Use Regex to Split Numbered List array into Numbered List Multiline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46331543/7690982)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple approach does not use *Regex*.  It assumes the data is in column **A** and the paragraphs are placed in column **B**:

```
Sub paragraph_no_regex()
    Dim s As String
    Dim ary

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        s = .TextJoin(" ", False, Columns(1).SpecialCells(2))
    End With

    ary = Split(s, "-")
    i = 1
    For Each a In ary
        Cells(i, 2) = a
        i = i + 1
    Next a
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub F()

    Dim re As New RegExp
    Dim sMatch As String
    Dim document As String

    re.Pattern = "-\n((.|\n)+?)\n-"

    'Getting document
    document = ...

    sMatch = re.Execute(document)(0).SubMatches(0)

End Sub
```

If you need dashes `-`, then just include them into capture group (the outer parenthesis).

Answer (score 0):

This RegEx matches your description and successfully extracts paragraphs (as tested on regex101.com):

```
matchPara = "-\n\d+\.\s*((?:.|\n)+?)\s*\n-"
```

It needs the 'global' flag but not the 'multiline' flag. Instead, the end-of-line token is matched in the regex. The main point is that the innermost matching group will match any character including the end-of-line (given as an alternative) but does so in a non-greedy way ("+?"). It doesn't care about word boundaries as this is not necessary here. Also, "-" is not a special character where used in the regex so it doesn't have to be escaped.

As added benefit leading and trailing whitespace is cut off ("\s*" outside the group).