# What is the best way to split a string containing lists of numbers, roman numbers, and bullets?

Tags: python, regex, split

I am trying to break up a string with multiple lists inside them with different formatting. What is the best way to do this?

```
string = "something here: 1) A i) great ii) awesome 2) B"

another_string = "But sometimes it is different (1) yep (2) not the same i. or this ii. another bullet (3.1) getting difficult huh? 3.1.1 okay i'm done"
```

Ideally, I would want to be able to split any possible numbering or bullet list.

Desired output for string:

```
something here: 1) A 
i) great 
ii) awesome 
2) B
```

Desired output for another_string:

```
But sometimes it is different (1) yep
(2) not the same
i. or this 
ii. another bullet
(3.1) getting difficult huh?
3.1.1 okay i'm done
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @Ajax1234 just revised my question

Comment: Ok sure, you could theoretically split with regex on numbers... however to make the code more general how would we handle the fact text could contain numbers? For instance: `(3.1)` 2.4 meters

Comment: @AntonvBR I suppose 2.4 will also get cut off as another substring of the string. Not sure there is another way around it.

Comment: @echan00 Yeah, but... the question here is. What is it your are trying to do? Do you want to validate the splits before output? Could possibly build a program that either splits or appends.

Comment: @AntonvBR I am trying to parse phrases/sentences out of a large number of documents. I'm using NLTK to parse sentences, but I see that many sentences have run on and included the numbered lists. I'm hoping to break those sentences into multiple pieces.

Comment: Ok, a googled quickly and think you can start by looking here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46331543/use-regex-to-split-numbered-list-array-into-numbered-list-multiline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.split` with the following regex (with the roman numeral regex borrowed from [paxdiablo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/267405/6890912)) to split the input string, and then join them with an iterator:

```
import re
def split(s):
    i = iter(re.split(r'(\(?\d+(?:\.\d+)+\)?|\(?\d+\)|\(?\b(?=M|(?:CM|CD|D?C)|(?:XC|XL|L?X)|(?:IX|IV|V?I))M{0,4}(?:CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(?:XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(?:IX|IV|V?I{0,3})[.)])', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
    return next(i) + '\n'.join(map(''.join, zip(i, i)))
```

so that with your sample inputs:

```
split(string)
```

would return:

```
something here: 1) A 
i) great 
ii) awesome 
2) B
```

and:

```
split(another_string)
```

would return:

```
But sometimes it is different (1) yep 
(2) not the same 
i. or this 
ii. another bullet 
(3.1) getting difficult huh? 
3.1.1 okay i'm done
```

Comment: Huh, big regex there, (makes me dizzy), :-), at least it still works:-)

Comment: This is awesome, but I'm noticing a few other problems.. Lists represented as (a), (b), (c), (A), (B), (C) are getting cut off. Abbreviations like Mr. and Mrs. are also getting cut off. Website urls such as www.google.com, www.sfc.com.hk also getting cut.

Comment: @echan00 I see. I've updated my answer with a fix. Please try it again.

Comment: I see a weird case where (i) wasn't split up and (ii) was split as '(' and 'ii)'. I also see a case where "(Cap." and "615)" was split up but not "(Cap. 486)". Any idea why?

Comment: @blhsing you've been awesome regardless, will mark answer as solved

Comment: You're welcome. Well you never mentioned that `(i)` and `(ii)` are valid separators. Updated my answer to account for them then. As for `486)`, it's a valid separator because it's in the same category as `1)`, unless you can define a clearer rule to exclude `486)` from being considered a separator.

Comment: @blhsing what would you change to have the first bullet after the colon also split separately on its own?